# Can i add attributes to columns in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, attributes, dynamic-columns

Example:

```
Create Table Person
(
Id Int Identity(1,1),
Name Varchar(50) Not Null Unique MYCUSTOMATTRIBUTE,
Age Int
)

Select is_identity, is_nullable From Sys.Columns
```

And how I can get it?...

Comment: You can join sys.[columns] C
LEFT JOIN sys.identity_columns IC ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id] - to find if it is an IDENTITY column

Comment: Not like that - no. But you can use [Extended Properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on tables, columns and more.

Comment: You can use Extended Properties as marc_s suggested. You also have the option of using data dictionary style tables external to the application data (roll your own or otherwise). Or you can go for a full blown tool like Erwin. Your best answer probably depends on what you want to accomplish by your custom attributes.